# Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection - Keyboard Locale

Tags: desktop, remote, keyboard-layout

I use Microsoft Remote Desktop connection (mstsc) to connect to work computer from home computer. They both have different keyboard layouts, One at office computer is European key board with keys mapped in places different that the keyboard at home computer.So when I use the Microsoft Remote Desktop connection and connect to office computer, it uses its own keyboard layout and Since that keyboard is not in front of me, I do not remember how the keys are mapped and hence end up struggling to get the right key pressed over the RDP connection.(e.g. when i am over the RDP connection and want to type a hash key, at a Linux xterm on the remote computer, but never find out its mapping on local computer keyboard, like here i wanted to type hash , but really lost it!)

Is there any way to make use of the local keyboard layout while using to input data on the remote desktop terminals/windows.

Anything in the options of Remote Desktop connection ?

any pointers will help.

thank you,

-AD.