# Remote Desktop: want remote locale by default, not the local one

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, keyboard-layout

> *Not a duplicate of [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection - Keyboard Locale](https://superuser.com/questions/200837/microsoft-remote-desktop-connection-keyboard-locale)*

Often I have to connect via remote desktop to my office PC. For various reasons, the default keyboard locale on my home computer is Russian, and default locale on the office PC is English-UK. Both home and office computers have Russian and English-UK layouts installed and available for Alt-Shifting.

The problem is that RD seems to set the local computer's default kb layout as the default layout for the remote computer for the duration of the session. That is, when I connect to the office PC, Russian keyboard layout is set as the default layout, so each program I start on the remote PC gets Russian layout by default, which I never want. For every lauched program, I have to Alt-Shift back to English-UK.

This is different from when I log in to the office PC locally, not using RD. Then English-UK is the default layout, which is exactly what I want at office.

How do I get RD to respect the remote default keyboard locale, so that I get English-UK by default even when connecting from a computer that has a different default layout?